# type="number" min and max attributes

Tags: html

why does type="number" not work for me, also I get a problem with min and max attributes.

For example the following:

```
<input type="number"  min="1" max="31" >
```

does not limit the users input to numbers within the range of 1 to 31, have I done this wrong or are these attributes worthless?

Comment: Not all attributes are supported in every browser, yet.

Comment: What browser are you using? Firefox? http://caniuse.com/input-number

Answer (score 0):

If a user tries to enter anything *except* a number between 1 and 31 (inclusive), form validation will fail in [supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/input-number).

Read more about [constraint validation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#constraint-validation) in the HTML standard, or about [form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) on MDN.

I should also note that on mobile devices, the numeric keyboard opens up when focusing on an `<input type=number>`, if the functionality is supported by the mobile browser.